# C++: How to copy a string object to an int array?

Tags: c++, linux, arrays, string

I have a string of numbers in C++: like string str="1234567012"

1. I wish to copy this to an int array, such that each element of the array will have one digit. Now I can use an iterator, and iterate one at a time and use `static_cast<int>(*iter)`. But is there any more easier and straightforward method?
2. finally i want to recopy the int array to a string array.

Please help me with above 2 steps.

Comment: Who downvoted? Thinking it as a non-programming question :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `std::transform` function:

```
std::vector<int> ints(str.size());
std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), ints.begin(),
               [](char c) { return c - '0'; });
```

If your compiler doesn't support lambdas yet, you can use a regular function:

```
int get_digit(char c) { return c - '0'; }

// ...
std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), ints.begin(), get_digit);
```

To do the reverse operation, you can do similarly:

```
std::string s(ints.size(), 0);
std::transform(ints.begin(), ints.end(), s.begin(),
               [](int i) { return i + '0'; });
```

Comment: Ahh..thanks a lot. Can you help with the last syntax: `[](char c) { return c - '0'; }`

Comment: That's a lambda. It's basically an anonymous function. That's a new feature in C++11, and it's already supported in some compilers. I added an alternative if you can't use that. The two snippets are equivalent.

Comment: You don't really need a `back_inserter`, it's probably simpler in this case just to create the vector big enough in the first place: `std::vector<int> ints(str.size()); std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), ints.begin(), lambda_or_function);`

Comment: Either way, it makes you appreciate `mylist = map(int, mystr)` (Python) ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: Peronally: I think it looks simpler to use a back inserter. For maintaining the code you now have a hard dependency on the lines being there rather than a single statement. Though I would still use reserve (as code will not break if it is accidentally removed).

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.reserve(str.size());
for (char c : str) { v.push_back(c - '0'); }

//...

string s;
for (int i : v)  { s += i + '0'; }
```

Comment: I am sorry, the earlier one was better. Can you please help me with the for loop? Never encountered this syntax before.

Comment: What does `char c: str` in for loop mean?

Comment: @kingsmasher1: it's a "range-based for statement", available in C++11. It does exactly what it looks like it does.

Comment: @kingsmasher1; `for(type x: cont) {/STUFF/}` => `for(iter loop=begin(cont); loop != end(cont); ++loop) {type x = *loop;/STUFF/}`

Comment: @LokiAstari: Thanks for the explanation, you made it easy.