# C++ error in using transform (STL)

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, stl, transform

I am facing a compilation error on using transform:

It is related to my previous question: [C++: How to copy a string object to an int array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944366/c-how-to-copy-a-string-object-to-an-int-array))

```
enter code here

 class BinaryCode {

    public:
            int get_digit(char c)
            {
                    return c-'0';
            }
            void decode(string decd)
            {
                    int i;

                    std::vector<int>decoded(decd.size());
                    std::transform(decd.begin(), decd.end(), decoded.begin(), get_digit);

                    int length=decoded.length();
```

The error is:

```
enter code here

[root@localhost topcoder]# g++ prog1.c
 prog1.c: In member function `void BinaryCode::decode(std::string)':
 prog1.c:20: error: argument of type `int (BinaryCode::)(char)' does not match `int (BinaryCode::*)(char)'
```

Can anyone please help me? I am using a gcc (g++) compiler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best IMHO would be to change the definition of

```
        int get_digit(char c)
```

to

```
        static int get_digit(char c)
```

It should work with this (static function). It is possible to transform using member functions, but it's slightly more complicated. Moreover, you don't need it.

Comment: This, or take it out of the class entirely.

Comment: Ahh..it worked. Thanks a ton. But why not non-static member function can be taken in last parameter?

Comment: @kingsmasher1: A member function isn't a function. Think about it. It cannot be invoked without also knowing the *object instance* on which you want to invoke it.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I got it, but i remember i created a static class (although not much in usage), and i invoked a member function via a destructor without any object or `this`

Comment: @kingsmasher1: There's no such thing as a "static class". You must be misremembering...

Comment: @KerrekSB: Me too thought the same like you - "no static class". FYI..just check the LeakTracer source code, and you will get to know. Also please update me of your views once you get to see the source code, where it has created a static class.

Comment: @kingsmasher1 if you're talking about something like `static class Foo;` that's not any different from a normal class in this regard. In C++ `static` on a class declaration just affects symbol visibility, but you'll still make instances of the class and you still have to have a `this` pointer to call member functions.

Comment: @bames53: You mean only global instances? LeakTracer static class has global instance only.

Comment: @kingsmasher1 No, `static class` does not have anything to do with making the class or instances 'global'. In this context `static` changes symbol visibility, making the class definition invisible outside the current translation unit. Otherwise it changes nothing about how the class behaves. You have to have an object or `this` pointer to invoke a member function of a `static` class in C++. `static class Foo{void bar();}; Foo f; f.bar(); // cannot call bar without an instance of Foo`

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a function or functor as the last parameter, not a member function. If you have c++11 enabled, you can use lambda :

```
std::transform(decd.begin(), decd.end(), decoded.begin(),[this](const char it){ this->get_digit(it) } );
```

---

Since you do not have c++11 features, you can convert get_digit, into a function (outside of the class):

```
int get_digit(char c)
{
  return c-'0';
}
class BinaryCode {
  public:
    void decode(string decd)
    {
      int i;

      std::vector<int>decoded(decd.size());
      std::transform(decd.begin(), decd.end(), decoded.begin(), get_digit);

      int length=decoded.length();
    }
};
```

or create a functor :

```
struct get_digit
{
  int operator()(char c) const
  {
      return c-'0';
  }
};

//...
std::transform(decd.begin(), decd.end(), decoded.begin(), get_digit());
//...
```

Comment: This must be the most awkward and cumbersome way to fake a free function via a member function...

Comment: My compiler does not accept this lambda form: `prog1.c: In member function `void BinaryCode::decode(std::string)':
prog1.c:21: error: expected primary-expression before '[' token
prog1.c:21: error: expected primary-expression before "const"
`

Comment: @KerrekSB I assumed that he used a member function, because he needs access to some member variables.

Answer (score 2):

1>
You can either move the get_digit outside the BinaryCode then your code would work

2>
or if you want get_digit to be a non-static member function, then you can use

```
  class BinaryCode {
    public:
        int get_digit(char c)
        {
                return c-'0';
        }
        void decode(string decd)
        {
            int i;
            std::vector<int>decoded(decd.size());
            std::transform(decd.begin(), decd.end(), decoded.begin(), std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&BinaryCode::get_digit),this));
        }

};
```

3>of course if you have access to either boost or c++11, then you can easily use lambda as others have already showed u.

Comment: Quite useful one, especially your 2nd point. But why do we have to bind it using mem_fun? Just binding using `bind1st` won't serve?